# Angular2: Unable to set initial value from ngModel on input type="date"

Tags: html, angular, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I am unable to get an initial date when using html5's <input type="date>

Here is what I have

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="testDate" />
```

in the component (this is in typescript) I am doing

```
testDate = new Date();
```

I have tried create a directive for the date field but

```
ElementRef.nativeElement.value = 'some date string'
```

doesn't seem to have any affect on the date being displayed. I've tried many different variations on the date string ('01-01-2016', '01/01/2016', '2016-01-01', and '2016/01/01'). If I change the text field then the ngModel field updates as expect. I am just having trouble with the initial date being displayed

Comment: Angular2 is not caring about date input. You will need to use string there (format yyyy-MM-dd if I remember it correctly).

Comment: I've tried that format already as '2016-01-01' sadly

Comment: Something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/bH7kwmw2h9RVKGQh17VT

Comment: You're right @HarryNinh I had tried it in another component and it all just started working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The format for the string I needed was 2016-01-01. FYI, I would recommend not using input type="date". It's nothing but a headache.